# Trouble styling block content using PortableText in Sanity v3 with Next.js and Tailwind CSS

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, sanity

I'm building a personal blog website using Sanity v3, Next.js 13, and Tailwind CSS. I have successfully implemented dynamic blogs using GROQ and everything is *almost* working. However, I'm facing difficulties styling the rendered block content using the PortableText component from the [@portabletext/react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@portabletext/react) package.

I have created a [RichTextComponents.jsx](https://github.com/w-dib/waliddib/blob/main/components/RichTextComponents.jsx) file where I define custom components for rendering different block types and marks.

Here's the code:

**RichTextComponents.jsx**

```js
/* eslint-disable @next/next/no-img-element */
import urlBuilder from "@sanity/image-url";
import { getImageDimensions } from "@sanity/asset-utils";

export const RichTextComponents = {
  types: {
    image: ({ value, isInline }) => {
      const { width, height } = getImageDimensions(value);
      return (
        <img
          src={urlBuilder()
            .image(value)
            .width(isInline ? 100 : 800)
            .fit("max")
            .auto("format")
            .url()}
          alt={value.alt || " "}
          loading="lazy"
          style={{
            // Display alongside text if image appears inside a block text span
            display: isInline ? "inline-block" : "block",

            // Avoid jumping around with aspect-ratio CSS property
            aspectRatio: width / height,
          }}
        />
      );
    },
  },

  block: {
    // Ex. 1: customizing common block types
    h1: ({ children }) => <h1 className="text-2xl text-red-400">{children}</h1>,
    blockquote: ({ children }) => (
      <blockquote className="border-l-purple-500">{children}</blockquote>
    ),

    // Ex. 2: rendering custom styles
    customHeading: ({ children }) => (
      <h2 className="text-lg text-primary text-purple-700">{children}</h2>
    ),
  },

  marks: {
    link: ({ children, value }) => {
      const rel = !value.href.startsWith("/")
        ? "noreferrer noopener"
        : undefined;
      return (
        <a
          href={value.href}
          rel={rel}
          className="text-blue-500 hover:text-blue-700"
        >
          {children}
        </a>
      );
    },
  },
};
```

In my blog page /app/blog/[blog]/page.js, I'm using the PortableText component to render the blog.body field value with the custom components:

```js
<PortableText value={blog.body} components={RichTextComponents} />
```

However, only the link `<a>` tags are being styled correctly. The images do not show up, and the h1, blockquote, and all other rich text elements are not being styled either, no matter what I try to add to the RichTextComponents file.

I have followed the documentation and examples provided by Sanity, but I can't figure out what I might be missing. I have also verified that the blog.body field does contain the appropriate block content. You can access a blog post [here](https://www.waliddib.com/blog/how-to-play-employee-retention-on-hard-mode).

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to properly style the block content using the PortableText component in Sanity v3 with Next.js and Tailwind CSS.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by adding the below:

```js
const imageBuilder = urlBuilder({
  projectId: "", // Replace with your Sanity project ID
  dataset: "", // Replace with your Sanity dataset
});
```

full code:

```js
/* eslint-disable @next/next/no-img-element */
import urlBuilder from "@sanity/image-url";
import { getImageDimensions } from "@sanity/asset-utils";
import Link from "next/link";

const imageBuilder = urlBuilder({
  projectId: "", // Replace with your Sanity project ID
  dataset: "", // Replace with your Sanity dataset
});

export const RichTextComponents = {
  types: {
    image: ({ value, isInline }) => {
      const { width, height } = getImageDimensions(value);
      return (
        <img
          src={imageBuilder.image(value).url()}
          alt={value.alt || " "}
          loading="lazy"
          className={`my-8 mx-auto ${
            isInline ? "max-w-xs" : "max-w-full"
          } rounded-lg shadow-lg`}
          style={{ aspectRatio: width / height }}
        />
      );
    },
  },

  block: {
    // Ex. 1: customizing common block types
    h1: ({ children }) => <h1 className="text-2xl text-red-400">{children}</h1>,
    blockquote: ({ children }) => (
      <blockquote className="border-l-purple-500">{children}</blockquote>
    ),

    // Ex. 2: rendering custom styles
    customHeading: ({ children }) => (
      <h2 className="text-lg text-primary text-purple-700">{children}</h2>
    ),
  },
  block: {
    h1: ({ children }) => (
      <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold my-4">{children}</h1>
    ),
    h2: ({ children }) => (
      <h2 className="text-3xl font-bold my-4">{children}</h2>
    ),
    h3: ({ children }) => (
      <h3 className="text-2xl font-bold my-4">{children}</h3>
    ),
    blockquote: ({ children }) => (
      <blockquote className="border-l-4 pl-4 my-4 italic text-gray-700 border-gray-300">
        {children}
      </blockquote>
    ),
    ul: ({ children }) => <ul className="list-disc ml-8 my-4">{children}</ul>,
    ol: ({ children }) => (
      <ol className="list-decimal ml-8 my-4">{children}</ol>
    ),
    li: ({ children }) => <li className="mb-2">{children}</li>,
    p: ({ children }) => <p className="text-xl my-4">{children}</p>,
  },
  marks: {
    link: ({ children, value }) => {
      const rel = !value.href.startsWith("/")
        ? "noreferrer noopener"
        : undefined;
      return (
        <Link
          href={value.href}
          rel={rel}
          className="text-blue-500 hover:text-blue-700"
        >
          {children}
        </Link>
      );
    },
  },
};
```